# why left click event works differently from right click or scroll?

Tags: objective-c, macos

so if you have 2 windows and you click on the one that is not active - it will activate and click event will not be propagated to window elements

if you right click or try to scroll with mouse over non-active window it will get events without being activated

why is that and can this behavior be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override NSView's `- (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent` to return YES in order to receive clicks when your app is inactive.